# How would I find the second asymptote of the following function:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I find the second vertical asymptote of $(2x^2)/(6x^2+11x-10)$?

I know that the first one is 2.5 from looking at a graphing calculator, but the second one is a small decimal asymptote, which I do not know how to find. Is there a way to do it mathematically?

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve $6x^2+11x-10=0$.

Now use the quadratic formula to find the roots.

$x=\dfrac{-11\pm\sqrt{11^2-4\cdot6\cdot-10}}{2\cdot6}=\dfrac{-11\pm19}{12}$

The first asymptote is $x=\dfrac{-11+19}{12}=\dfrac{8}{12}=\dfrac{2}{3}$, the second asymptote is $x=\dfrac{-11-19}{12}=\dfrac{-30}{12}=\dfrac{-5}{2}=-2\dfrac{1}{2}$.

---

**Edit**

In general, we find the vertical asymptote(s) of a rational function $f(x)=\dfrac{g(x)}{h(x)}$ by solving $h(x)=0$. If $g(x)=0$ and $h(x)=0$ for the same $x$, then we have removable discontinuity (hole in the graph).

Comment: would you take into account the 2x^2?

Comment: No, the vertical asymptote only involves setting the denominator equal to zero.

Comment: @Arithmetician no, that is not an asymptote. Vertical asymptotes are caused by zeros in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have $x=2.5$ as a root of the denominator, which corresponds to $x=2.5$ or $2x-5=0$. Taking this as a factor we obtain $$6x^2+11x-10=(2x-5)(3x+2)$$ giving a second root $x=-\frac 23$. It remains to check that this is not also a root of the numerator (obvious here).